# How to listen to screen orientation change when auto-rotate is disabled in Android?

Tags: android, autorotate

In my app i disable the auto-orientation but i still want to listen to orientation change method.
I tried overriding `onConfigurationChanged` but i guess it's not called when auto-rotate is disabled.
I'm building on API 8 .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at how to read the accelerometer or gyroscope, to do this. I'm not really sure if this works or not, but that's how I would start out. Here's a link on how to use the accelerometer data.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Comment: I thought about reading the angle from the sensor directly but it appears to be too much unstable so it will be kept changing even when the phone is placed on a flat surface which then i will have to start performing calculations and add some threshold / hysteresis which i wouldn't like to do...

Comment: does this help you ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248274/android-detect-orientation-changed

Comment: Well ... it will probably do the job, but i'm more afraid of the memory this app will consume when running the code there (it will be called non stopped since the sensor is changing all the time) and it might be too much, but i guess that's an option

Comment: Remember that all android apps are limited to 32MB of memory as far as I remember, as long as you don't go past this, you should be fine. It's hard for me to say anything about this, as I'm not really introduced to what you're doing :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code myself in my app:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

The value of `rotation` can be as follows: 1 or 3 for landscape and 0 or 2 for portrait.

I'm not 100% sure if this will work if auto rotation is disabled, though, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Okay, this is trickier than I thought... I use it in the `onCreate` method, but since you disable the auto-orientation, it will not be invoked when the screen is rotated...