# Dynamic android:orientation value for LinearLayout depending on device orientation without the need for 2 identical XML layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a XML layout that works just fine on a landscape and portrait orientation with one exception - two buttons inside a LinearLayout need to be placed horizontally on landscape and vertically on portrait device orientation.

I was wondering if there is some easy way to just define a dynamic variable or a string that can be placed in the XML layout file, without having to have to make 2 identical copies of it in `layout` and `layout-land` folders.

Comment: Consider using re-usable layouts with <include> or <merge> directives http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing it programmatically:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     // landscape
     linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
} else {
    // portrait  
    linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16690483/1514026)

Answer (score 1):

Orientation is an enum under the hood with 0 serving as horizontal and 1 serving as vertical. What I did is in `res/values/integer.xml` I placed a default entry for landscape as 0 and then in `res/values-port/integer.xml` I placed the same entry but with value 1.

So I have:

/res/values/integer.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="linearlayoutOrientation" type="integer">0</item>
</resources>
```

/res/values-port/integer.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="linearlayoutOrientation" type="integer">1</item>
</resources>
```

And then in my layout file I declare orientation as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="@integer/linearlayoutOrientation">
```

Comment: That's the best solution by far.