# Android: start new activity on orientation changed, without recreating old activity

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I need to start new activity when user sets the device in landscape orientation without changing orientation of the old activity.

So, I have 2 activities:

- (1) Old activity in portrait only
- (2) New activity in landscape only

The app scenario looks like this:

- user is in (1) old activity in portrait mode
- user puts his device landscape, I need to start (2) new activity
- user is in (2) new activity and presses Back button. I need to finish new (2) activity and come back to (1) old activity which
  should be still in portrait orientation (even if the device is in
  landscape orientation).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: why would you want to do such a thing, that sounds like a frustrating user experience

Comment: My client asks me to do so :)

Comment: I managed to solve this, according to the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248274/android-detect-orientation-changed