# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I tried searching all SO questions but seems its because missing setContentView or need clean the project, my issue its i got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id but its "random" i can't figure out why some devices throw this exception i have
Activity->FragmentA->Nested fragment 
and works great but sometimes after a lot of time when i try to open my app crash this its the code in OncreateView

```
if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            try {

                FragmentDestination f = FragmentDestination.newInstance(null,null);
                f.setOnDestinationSelectedListener(this);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.destinationHolder,f).commit();
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

        }
```

This seems to work well but some time the exception its raised (destinationHolder its a frameLayout container)

and sometimes if i use
Activity->FragmentA->Nested FragmentA-> replaceFragmentA
using the next code sometimes raise the exception.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nested_fragment_a,f).commit();
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your activity or fragment isn't being properly cached and a re-creation crashes the app.

Try calling

```
super.onCreate(null);
```

and see if the problem goes away. If so then you'll need to properly save the instance states for your fragments and activity, so they're re-created properly.

You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) and [here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26966623/3249477) which had this problem.