# How do I get the orientation of the device when the app is locked in one direction?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-orientation

I am trying to make pictures using the camera be oriented correctly when saved. I tried using the orientation sensor but it can't seem to be calibrated. I wanted to just grab the orientation like this: [How can I get the current screen orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation) but it seems that locking your app as a portrait only app means it will always return portrait only.

So how do I get the screens real orientation despite the app being locked in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get activity orientation, then try this:

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

If you want to get android device orientation, then try this :

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

If you face orientation issue with device camera, then you will try following code snippet to set camera orientation :

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {   
    p.set("orientation", "portrait");
    p.set("rotation",90);
}
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{                               
    p.set("orientation", "landscape");          
    p.set("rotation", 90);
}
```

Comment: `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` and `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` always return Portrait for me.

`IWindowManager windowManager = Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
                var orientation3 = windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;` Also always returns Rotation0 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that worked for me based on this response. [Android: Detect Orientation Changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248274/android-detect-orientation-changed) . I made a OrientationListener. Orientation is in degrees and is exactly what I needed.

```
    internal class MyOrientationListener : global::Android.Views.OrientationListener
{
    private MainActivity _parent;
    public MyOrientationListener(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _parent = (MainActivity)context;
    }

    public override void OnOrientationChanged(int orientation)
    {
        _parent.GlobalOrientation = orientation;
    }
}
```

Edit: Note this is for xamarin. I setup this in the MainActivity in CreateBundle(bundle) like this: `_orientationListener = new QuarcOrientationListener(this);`

Don't forget to .Enable()/.Disable() it in OnPause and OnResume in the activity.