# Prevent layout change and still catch onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, orientation

I need to lock the layout for a fragment in order to prevent it from rotating when the device is rotated to landscape.

To do that, I locked it in the manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait
```

The layout doesn't change, but I still need to do some work when the orientation is changed (rotate the buttons). Locking it this way prevents onConfigurationChanged from being called.

The behavior I'm aiming is exactly like the default camera app. When you rotate the device, the layout stays the same, but only the buttons rotate.

Has anyone a trick to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen for simple screen orientation changes *programmatically* and have your application react to them, you can use [the  **OrientationEventListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) class to do this within your Activity.

Implementing orientation event handling in your Activity is simple. Simply instantiate an `OrientationEventListener` and provide its implementation. For example, the following Activity class called `SimpleOrientationActivity` logs orientation information to LogCat:

```
public class SimpleOrientationActivity extends Activity {
    OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,
                    "Orientation changed to " + orientation);
            }
        };

       if (mOrientationListener.canDetectOrientation() == true) {
           Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Can detect orientation");
           mOrientationListener.enable();
       }
       else {
           Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Cannot detect orientation");
           mOrientationListener.disable();
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mOrientationListener.disable();
    }
}
```

For more help, see [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2262133&seqNum=4).

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248274/android-detect-orientation-changed) will help.

Comment: I thought there would be a built-in way to do it, using screenOrientation and OnConfigurationChanged, but this will do the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the orientation programmatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
```

And detect orientation changes in code using this:

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     // Do something here...
 }
```

Comment: As I specified in the original post, locking the screen in a way will prevent onConfigurationChanged from being called. This method will never be called because of the first instruction